# TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly while creating a bucket using boto client library plugin

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, boto

[Boto client library plugin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-plugin)

This code is used to create a bucket but I couldn't

```
import boto  
import time

# URI scheme for Cloud Storage. 
GOOGLE_STORAGE = 'gs'
# URI scheme for accessing local files. 
LOCAL_FILE = 'file'

now = time.time()

CATS_BUCKET = 'cats-%d' % now 
DOGS_BUCKET = 'dogs-%d' % now

print(CATS_BUCKET) 
print(DOGS_BUCKET)

for name in (CATS_BUCKET, DOGS_BUCKET):
    # Instantiate a BucketStorageUri object.
    uri = boto.storage_uri(name, GOOGLE_STORAGE)
    # create bucket
    try:
        uri.create_bucket()
        print("Successfully created bucket {}".format(name))
    except boto.exception.StorageCreateError as e:
        print("Failed to create bucket: ", e)
```

I have set up the .boto file and when I run this I'm getting error like

```
path = '/' + bucket
```

TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: Which line raised the error ? And please copy paste the code, dont post screen shots

Comment: You should use `boto3` instead of `boto`. `boto` has been basically EOL for years.

Comment: uri.create_bucket() raised the error

Answer (score 0):

You can try to decode the uri before using it :

```
uri.decode('utf-8')
```

Or you can read it already as utf-8 from the beginning with something like that :

```
with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8') as file:
  uri = file.read()
```

I honestly think that this issue is related to the encoding. If my suggestion does not work let me know and I will look further into this direction.

**EDIT:**

You can try also to get the "uri" object like this :

```
 uri = boto.storage_uri("%s/%s" % (BUCKET_NAME, DOWNLOAD_PATH), 'gs')
```

Comment: I tried uri.decode('utf-8') but I got an error: AttributeError: 'BucketStorageUri' object has no attribute 'decode'